# Discretization and reformulation into a linear programming problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Minimize $$\int_0^N|a(x)|dx$$
$$\ddot y(x)=a(x)-c,$$
$$y(N) = d,$$
$$y(x)\ge0,\quad x\in[0,N]$$

I’ve come across a problem that wants me to discretize and then reform it into a linear programming problem. **y ̈** is the second derivative of y, N = 20, d = 15 and c = 16. I’ve thought of dividing the planning horizon [0, N] into n smaller periods where nΔ=T and replacing the integration with summation but couldn’t continue this thought process.

How would I go about solving this problem, how would I take care of the absolute value in the objective function?

Comment: Do not post unsearchable images.  Instead, use *MathJax*.

Comment: Converted it into the appropriate notation, posting an unsearchable image wasn't my intention.

Comment: Thank you.......